# Cannot clone virtual device in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

Clone Device button doesn't work in Android Studio (ver 2.1.2) and when I try to click "Clone Device" button an error appears:

> NullPointerException: null

Comment: where is that button located exactly?

Comment: What type of hardware profile are you attempting to clone?  Does clone work with another profile?

Comment: Clone doesn't work with another profile. It doesn't work with any other hardware.The button is in Virtual Device Configuration>Select Hardware>Phone on the right corner of the "Virtual Device Configuration" window .